# Using both AND, OR in If condition Javascript

Tags: javascript

Similar questions haven't justified my actual question.
I have a If condition where if it satisfies 2 conditions it should set value as A else B. Below is the code block describing my question

```
if(($form[0].lang.value==SPN||PTB||GRM) && ("1" == "<awi:script script='IsTranslationON'/>"))
    {
    $form[0].$rtag.value = "Test"+$form[0].lang.value+"_"+$form[1].take1.value+"_SUPPORT_Translation";
     }
    else
      {$form[0].$rtag.value = "Test"+$form[0].lang.value+"_"+$form[1].take1.value+"_SUPPORT";}
 //Submit form
      submit=false;
      if(submit){$form[0].submit()}else{alert($form[0].$rtag.value)}
```

Issue is - evrytime it gets deiplayed only statement from If condition. It is not checking value with `$lang.value`
Does any of the mates help me checking my if condition please.
EDIT- The value I am getting in alert box is "Test_IND_GENERAL_SUPPORT_Translation".

Comment: `"1" == "<awi:script ...`? what is it for a language?

Comment: This is a system value I am getting it is 1 which is true in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is comparision I am doing and " " are must.Every suggestion here helped me to dig in.
I am in intermediate stage yet.

```
(($form[0].lang.value=="SPN"||$form[0].lang.value=="PTB"||$form[0].lang.value=="GRM")
```

Answer (score 4):

This `$form[0].lang.value==SPN||PTB||GRM` is incorrect. You need to write a new condition check for each of these expected values. EG

```
if($form[0].lang.value==SPN || $form[0].lang.value== PTB ... etc )
```

Comment: as it's written the values are variables.

Comment: Your solution helped me to debug the issue.
But I missed  " " there which in turn chnaged to assigning the values rather than comparing. 
It should be `$form[0].lang.value=="SPN" || $form[0].lang.value== "PTB" `

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$form[0].lang.value==SPN||PTB||GRM
```

Will compare `$form[0].lang.value` with `SPN` and then *logical OR* `PTB` and `GRM`. If any of `PTB` and `GRM` is *truthy value*, then this condition will succeed.

If `SPN, PTB and GRM` are variables, then put them in an array first.

```
var langArr =  [ SPN, PTB, GRM ];
if((langArr.indexOf( $form[0].lang.value) !=  - 1 ) && ("1" == "<awi:script script='IsTranslationON'/>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a concise check, you could put the values into an array and check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
[SPN, PTB, GRM].includes($form[0].lang.value)
```